# SQL Join Critera in CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a CASE statement on the JOIN critera of an SQL statement. I've tried with the below, but I still received an error with invalid syntax around the '' or =

What I'm trying to achieve is, to JOIN the configtable on different critera, depending on whether the @machineID variable is equal to a space or not.

Could someone advise whether it's my syntax which is incorrect, or if it's not possible? I'd like to know the theory behind it, not just a solution.

```
Declare @MachineID int
Declare @TypeID int
Select @MachineID = 1
Select @TypeID = 1

INSERT #Results1 (ID, CustomerID, MachineID, NewStatus, StatusTime)
SELECT A.ID, C.CustomerID, A.MachineID, A.NewStatus, A.StatusTime
FROM Statetable A
INNER JOIN Configtable B
ON CASE WHEN @MachineID = ''
THEN A.StateID = B.StateID AND A.MachineID = B.MachineID AND B.TypeID = @TypeID
WHEN @MACHINEID <> = '' THEN...
```

Comment: It's generally much better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in ON and WHERE clauses.

Comment: if the condition is not based on the data inside the table then I recommend using some procedural logic.

Comment: CASE is not a control-of-flow statement. It is an expression. Once you understand the difference, you will be far more successful in applying it to your solutions. See the first answer and learn the concept. In addition, you need to understand datatypes. You defined @MachineID as int yet you compare it to an empty string literal. This does not make logical sense, but unfortunately it works because the db engine will convert an empty string to zero. But don't rely on sloppy coding and assumptions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I can see the difference now between the control of flow/expression.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it that way. You can do it like this:

```
ON 
(@MachineID = '' 
  AND  A.StateID = B.StateID AND A.MachineID = B.MachineID AND B.TypeID = @TypeID)
OR 
(@MACHINEID <> = '' 
  ...
```